# Is there a way to send one email to a contact that has multiple entries in a Marketing Cloud Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I believe the answer is no but I'd like to see if maybe there is something I've overlooked.

We have a custom object in Salesforce that we use to track training completions and expiration dates. We'd like to be able to send a summary email of upcoming expirations using a Marketing Cloud import into a Journey. If a contact has multiple upcoming expirations, they would have multiple entries in the Data Extension and thus the journey would send them an email for each entry. I was hoping there might be a way using Ampscript (or another built in MC function) to grab the details of all their entries in the DE and send them one email via the Journey.

We think we might have to do a SOQL query or server-side Javascript to manipulate the imported DE to only have one entry per contact, with their upcoming expirations concatenated into one field but I was hoping there might be a solution without that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom object will be synced to Marketing Cloud, so you can query the records in there using SQL Activities in Automation Studio. This will allow you to create a single sendable data extension, with deduplicated recipient records. This will be your entry data for Journey Builder.

Within your email, you will be able to use [LookupRows](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/) function to fetch all the records in your custom object, which have expirations belonging to the particular recipient. This is a common use case, as placing all the data in a single data extension is not necessary. You could also use [LookupOrderedRows](https://ampscript.guide/lookuporderedrows/), to return the records with e.g. these expiring earliest, as first records.